# How is takeWhile different from filter?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-9

How is takeWhile() different from filter() in Java 9. What extra utility does it have?

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).filter(i -> i < 4 )
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is perhaps what following would do

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).takeWhile(i -> i < 4 )
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

What was the need of this new function then?

Comment: A quick google search came up with [this](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-stream/): "Called on an ordered stream it will return a new one that consists of those element that passed the predicate until the first one failed. It’s a little like filter but it cuts the stream off as soon as the first element fails the predicate. _In its parlance, it takes elements from the stream while the predicate holds and stops as soon as it no longer does._" - If you'd change your predicate to get odd elements only `filter()` would result in `1,3,5,7,9` while `takeWhile()` would result in just `1`.

Comment: Okay. So perhaps it is a more narrowed down form of `filter`.

Comment: In fact this is why there is a `while` in the function name indicating `break` if predicate does not hold.

Comment: You got it :) ..

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`filter` will remove all items from the stream that do not satisfy the condition.

`takeWhile` will abort the stream on the first occurrence of an item which does not satisfy the condition.

e.g.

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
    .filter(i -> i < 4 )
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

will print

> 123321

but

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
    .takeWhile(i -> i < 4 )
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

will print

> 123

Answer (score 15):

## The difference

### takeWhile

Takes values while the filter is true, then stops

### filter

Takes all the values that match the filter

## Example

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).filter(i -> i % 2 == 0 )
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##LU1LDoIwEN33FLMxgWSc@FckuHPpihNUBBwslLSDiTGcHRv1bV7yvo1@6rnty665PZJp4ra3TqAJKg3Chry4UreUfylVhdHew0Vz91b9cDVcgBctgZ6Wb9AGIwpZ7moiAu1qH8Nb/dpkq2iJK1zjBre4wz0eMMHlIqaKjZQuYpifgGEGK8gyWECs4A@qrDvr4h7lLy9lWBrkeOzDjZguTtWoxmn6AA)

This outputs all of the even numbers from 2 to 10 inclusive.

```
Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10).takeWhile(i -> i % 2 == 0 )
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##LU27CsJAEOzvK7YRElgX35qIdpZWFtZrPHXjJRdyG0HEb4@HOs3APEt@8NA3ti7P96zvpWp8q1BGlToVR0FbyxUdvrQ2heMQYM9Sv0zTnZwUEJQ10sPLGapoJDEr9ZWIgNtrSOFlfm3yl2SME5ziDOe4wCWuMMPxKCXluz3exNlEYLgFgQFMYLOBEaQG/qCLb3dc3JLDM6iNY53meROf1NXp2rzNu@8/)

This outputs nothing, as 1 is not even, so it stops before outputing anything.

Comment: Love the [TIO](https://tio.run/#) links! Very handy for future reference and possible use here.

Comment: does these operators `take*, skip*` end the observable and unsubscribe subscribers? like `take(1)` does?

Answer (score 3):

According to this blogpost: https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-stream/

> Called on an **ordered stream** it will return a new one that consists of those element that passed the predicate **until the first one failed**. It’s a little like filter but it **cuts the stream off as soon as the first element fails** the predicate. In its parlance, it takes elements from the stream while the predicate holds and stops as soon as it no longer does.

i marked the important stuff in bold.

The example from the post:

```
Stream.of("a", "b", "c", "", "e")
    .takeWhile(s -> !String.isEmpty(s));
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

Outputs `abc`. Because it filters until the first one doesn't match the predicate (in the example the 4th element). So you could say it's shortcircuiting the stream.

Answer (score 2):

It could be used to get the index of the first `null` value e.g.

```
Stream.of("Test", "Test2", null, "Test2", null).takeWhile(Objects:isNull).count();
```

You could do the same with `filter` but in that case you would need to have a condition to break the filter as soon as you get the first null value. So in practice `filter` is not suited for that kind of work while `takeWhile` is exactly for that case.

Comment: this doesn't necessarily hold true.

Answer (score -1):

The operations **takeWhile** and **dropWhile** are more efficient than a filter if you know that the source is **sorted**. These operations make use of short-circuiting and that means: a computation stops as a result is found, there is no need to process the whole stream with filter operation